# Definition of the volume functional of convex and star bodies.

Tags: measure-theory, definition, volume, convex-geometry, discrete-geometry

I’m reading up on mixed volume. Since my calculus is a bit rusty and I’ve never taken measure theory (I read and understood the definition of Hausdorff measure given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure)), I have a few questions about the definition of the volume functional. The following are some relevant definitions.

> For a compact starshaped set $K$, the radial function is defined by
> $$
> \rho(K, x):=\max \{\lambda \geq 0: \lambda x \in K\}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \backslash\{o\}
> $$

> Here $\mathcal{K}^{n}$ and $\mathcal{S}_{o}^{n}$ are the sets of convex bodies and star bodies in $\mathbb{R}^n$, respectively.

Also

> For a subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ its characteristic function is defined by
> $$
> \mathbf{1}_{A}(x):=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
> 1 & \text { for } x \in A, \\
> 0 & \text { for } x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \backslash A,
> \end{array}\right.
> $$

> The volume functional $V_{n}$ on $\mathcal{K}^{n}$ or $\mathcal{S}_{o}^{n}$ is defined as the restriction of the $n$ -dimensional Hausdorff measure $\mathcal{H}^{n}$ to $\mathcal{K}^{n}$ or $\mathcal{S}_{o}^{n}$, respectively. Most suitable for computing the volume of a star body $K$ is the radial function, since the use of spherical coordinates immediately gives
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> V_{n}(K) &=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \mathbf{1}_{K}(x) \mathrm{d} x=\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} \mathbf{1}_{K}(r u) r^{n-1} \mathrm{~d} u \mathrm{~d} r \\
> &=\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} \int_{0}^{\rho(K, u)} r^{n-1} \mathrm{~d} r \mathrm{~d} u
> =\frac{1}{n} \int_{\mathbb{S} n-1} \rho(K, u)^{n} \mathrm{~d} u
> \end{aligned} $$

In the expression for $V_n(K)$, how do we get $r^{n-1}$ in the second equality? Say $\bf{0} \in K$ (which is also the author’s assumption for starshaped bodies), then to me the double integral seems akin to taking the sum of all “rays” emanating from $\bf{0}$. But then shouldn’t we restrict the domain to vectors $ru$ that lie on the boundary of $K$, and shouldn’t we have just $r$ instead of $r^{n-1}$?

Comment: The final equality looks like it's just usual integration: $\int_0^\rho r^{n-1} dr=\frac{1}{n}\rho^n$

Comment: Yes! Thanks. I misread the integrand so it didn’t make sense.

Comment: For question 1, think of the case where $n=3$. Then, your first integral is integrating a characteristic function, which is the same of the measure of the set $K$ in space. In this case $S^{2}$ is the sphere and you are integrating $r$ from $0$ to $\infty$. Here your integrals tell you integrate over the sphere centered at $\vec{0}$ as its radius increases. This will eventually recover all of $3$-space.

Comment: Basically it's just another way of covering the same ground, $\mathbb{R}^3$, and the corresponding change of variables.

Comment: I don’t get why we have $r^{n-1}$ in the formula though. Say $\bf{0} \in K$ (which is also the author’s assumption for starshaped bodies), then to me the double integral seems akin to taking the sum of all “rays” emanating from $\bf{0}$. But then shouldn’t we restrict the domain to vectors $ru$ that lie on the boundary of $K$, and shouldn’t we have just $r$ instead of $r^{n-1}$?

Comment: Right, but the sphere $S^{n-1}$ is $(n-1)$-dimensional so you pick up $n-1$ $r$'s. If you give me a moment, I can write up a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better explanation of the change of variables I mention in the comments:

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and notice that any nonzero vector can be written uniquely as a product of a direction on the unit sphere $u \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ and a scalar $r\in [0,\infty)$. That is,

$$
x=(x_1,\dots,x_n) = r(u_1,\dots,u_n) = ru.
$$

Our first candidate for the change of variables map $F:(r,u)\mapsto ru$ is deceiving when written like this because really we mean:

$$
F:(r,u_1,\dots,u_n)\mapsto (ru_1,\dots,ru_n).
$$

So we hope that by the change of variables formula:

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}1_K(x)dx = \int_0^\infty \int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} 1_K(ru) |det DF|drdu
$$

where $DF$ is the Jacobian of $F$. Unfortunately, this means we need to fix our map $F$ so that a determinant makes sense. Computing it is a bit tedious in TeX and I am being a bit blase with details. But note that $u_n = \sqrt{1-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} u_{i}^2}$ so $F$ can be rewritten such that $DF$ is square $n\times n$ and from the determinant you get $n-1$ $r$'s in the integrand. By rewrite $F$ I mean:

$$
\tilde F: (r,u_1,\dots,u_{n-1})\mapsto (ru_1,\dots,ru_{n-1},r\sqrt{1-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} u_{i}^2})
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had to do a quick look at the substitution theorem for multiple variables, and thing starts to clear up a bit. So as I understand it, the $r^{n-1}$ comes from $|\text{det}DF|$? Would it be correct to say that a typical term of the Jacobian would be $\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial u_i} = \frac{\partial (ru_i)}{\partial u_i} = r$? From there how do we get the determinant? If it’s more convenient you can just write some note on paper and upload it to imgur instead of using TeX. Please bear with me as my calculus is really rusty.